# sub-sub-folders in Thunderbird

Tags: email, linux-mint, thunderbird

I am trying to create folders in my Thunderbird mail inbox for the convenience of sorting my incoming mails. However, Thunderbird only allows me to add two layers of folders. I did not include photos here because I didn't figure out how to include the dropdown menus in screenshots. So let me describe what happens.

I right-click on "Posteingang" (Inbox) (language is German) of one of my mail accounts. A dropdown menu opens, in which I can choose, among others, "Neuer Ordner ..." (New folder ...). In the opening window, I give the folder the name "StackExchange".
Right-clicking on the subfolder "StackExchange" opens another dropdown menu, where I can choose (among others) "Neuer Unterordner ..." (New subfolder ...). I click "Neuer Unterordner ..." and give it the name "SuperUser".
Yet another right-click on the subfolder "SuperUser" opens a dropdown menu which *does not* contain the option "Neuer Unterordner ...".

I am confused upon this behaviour, since I have worked with Thunderbird before (operating system Linux Mint 18.x (Mate)). There, it allowed me to add (sub)^{n}-folders as I desired.
Recently, I installed Linux Mint 20.2 (Mate) on the laptop. Now I try to configure Thunderbird (which was installed automatically) and get the described problem.

Thanks for your help! If this question should not be suitable for superuser.stackexchange, then please give me a hint where to ask it instead.

**Edit:** Apparently, I am not always able to reproduce the described behaviour. As far as I see for now, the misbehaviour occurs or doesn't occur depending on the overlying mail account. I cannot create subsubfolders in my gmx.net-address, but I can create subfolders in the mail account provided by my institution.
Both accounts are configured as IMAP.

Comment: Is the account in which this doesn't work IMAP or POP? And what is the account that does work? For IMAP, do you have in *Tools > Account Settings > Server Settings > Advanced > IMAP* an option for "Server supports folders that contain subfolders and messages"; if you do then uncheck it.

Comment: Hi @harrymc, both accounts are IMAP, and in both accounts I found the box "Server supports folders that contain subfolders and messages" ticked. Unticking it in the misbehaving account did not yet change anything.

Comment: Maybe gmx.net does not allow for subsubfolders? I couldn't find anything in that direction on the internet in a quick search, but possibly I had my gmx.net account configured as POP before and hence didn't get that behaviour on my old installation.

Comment: IMAP only shows what is on server, so it's very likely that it's the server that is restricting subfolders. I suggest getting in touch with their Support. With POP, the subfolders are purely on your side, so no restrictions.

Comment: OK, well, I contacted the GMX support. They replied that the German customer service is responsible for my issue, hence I have to contact them. However, the FreeMail support is not free. Hence I think I will give up on this issue, believing that my problem comes from a restriction on GMX' side.

Comment: I have summed up our discussion in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With POP the sub-folders are purely on your side, so there are
no restrictions.

However, IMAP only shows what is on the server, so it's very
likely that it's the server that is restricting the levels of
sub-folders.

I suggest getting in touch with their Support
(if possible and not costly).